# Replies when DM is successfully sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a code to send someone a DM, but if the user has DM disabled it will reply that DMs are disabled.

```
 mention.send("A message.").catch(() => message.reply("User has DM disabled, cannot send message."));
```

But I want the bot to reply with something like `Message has been sent`. Thank you.

Comment: do you want this reply to be in the place where you typed the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
mention.send("A message.")
.then(() => message.reply("Message has been sent."))
.catch(() => message.reply("User has DM disabled, cannot send message."));
```